# How to change a file name in R?

Tags: r

I am doing some calculations and would like to name the resultant files with the same name of the original files but with additions of `res` to the files.

```
dir1<- list.files("/data/mydat", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
dir1
# [1] /data/mydat/1258_file.img
outputDir  <- "/data/myresluts"
outputFile <- file.path(outputDir, basename(dir1[1]))
outputFile
# [1] "/data/myresluts/1258_file.img"
```

What I need is just to add `_res` to the outputFile name to be like this:

```
1258_file_res.img
```

Is this posible in R?

Comment: try  `gsub('.img', '_res.img', basename(dir1[1]))`

Comment: There is also the file.rename() function as well as similar functions that can be found using the command ?files

Comment: Also you can avoid using `basename()` if you do not use `fill.names = T` while listing the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the rest of your files are named, you could just use a sample substitution. Suppose you had a file name,

```
fname = "/data/myresluts/1258_file.img"
```

We just need to replace `.img` with `_res.img`, i.e.

```
R>  gsub(".img", "_res.img", fname) 
[1] "/data/myresluts/1258_file_res.img"
```

Answer (score 3):

- use strsplit to separate filename from its extension

  ```
  a<-strsplit(basename(dir1[1]), '[.]')[[1]]
  ```
- Concatenate the base file-name with your desired string('_res')

  ```
  a[1]<- paste(a[1],'res',sep='_')
  ```
- Again concatenate the resultant string with original file extension

  ```
  paste(a[1],a[2],sep='.')
  ```